# How to give permissions for users to the related objects in django?

Tags: django, permissions

I have a standard blog application with articles and categories. One category has many  articles. 
Users in admin panel can add new articles. What is the better way to give my users permissions to specific categories? E.g. editor can add only articles connected with 'A' category and can't add article to 'B' category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the django-permissions app: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-permissions

It allows you to specify permissions on a per-object basis. That is, you can say UserA has permissions specifically for CategoryA, as opposed to the django default of per-model permissions.

**Update**

For some reason, the author of this app didn't update their pypi page with the proper location of the code repository. For reference, he renamed it to: https://bitbucket.org/diefenbach/django_permissions/overview

Comment: You can do it either from the admin panel or in code. Take a look at the `utils.py` module for some really easy functions. Also, look at the `tests.py` module to see exactly how they are used with examples.

Comment: [django-guardian](http://packages.python.org/django-guardian/) is another option to do per-object permissions.

Comment: There are really a number of them on pypi. Its just a matter of choosing one that has good docs and recent activity